# Value of one variable could not be assigned to other

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code
-which inputs a number
-if its largest replace its value at variable large(It is currently set at largest = None)
-same process for smallest
-done is entered to stop code and print largest and smallest
Code is below

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        num = int(num) #captcha for user if he enters anything else than integer,
                        #it won't convert to int and move to except
        
        if largest < num:
            largest = num
            continue
        elif smallest > num:
            smallest = num
            continue
    except:
        try:
            if num == "done" :break
        except:
            print ("Invalid input")
            continue
print ("Maximum", largest)
print ("Minimum", smallest)
```

when it is executed with the values 7, 2, bob, 10,4 and done it supposed to output

```
Invalid input
Maximum is 10
Minimum is 2
```

But it just says

```
Maximum None
Minimum None
```

Comment: You can't compare `None` with an integer, so your `if` statements always cause a `TypeError` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0
flag = True
while True:
    try:
        inputValue = input("Enter value: ")
        if inputValue == "Done":
            flag = False
            break
        if type(int(inputValue)) is int:
            inputValue = int(inputValue)
            if largest < inputValue:
                largest = inputValue
                continue
            elif smallest > inputValue:
                smallest = inputValue
                continue
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

print("Maximum: ", largest)
print("Minimum: ", smallest)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `None` with numbers. Keep the first number as the max and min value, then compare the rest. For this, use a counter `c`.

```py
largest = 0
smallest = 0
c = 0
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        num = int(num) #captcha for user if he enters anything else than integer,
                        #it won't convert to int and move to except
        if c == 0:
            smallest = num
            largest = num
        elif largest < num:
            largest = num
            continue
        elif smallest > num:
            smallest = num
            continue
    except:
        try:
            if num == "done" :break
        except:
            print ("Invalid input")
            continue
    c += 1
print ("Maximum", largest)
print ("Minimum", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare `None` to an `int` with smaller than `<` and greater than `>` operators, which does not work. You should probably instantiate `smallest` and `largest` to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this code, but tried to fix errors:

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    v = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        num = int(v) 
        
        if largest in None or largest < num:
            largest = num
            continue
        if smallest is None or smallest > num:
            smallest = num
            continue
    except ValueError:
        if v == "done":
             break
        print ("Invalid input")
print ("Maximum:", largest)
print ("Minimum:", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        num = int(num) #captcha for user if he enters anything else than integer,
                        #it won't convert to int and move to except
        list1.append(num)

    except:
        try:
            if num == "done" :break
        except:
            print ("Invalid input")
            continue
print ("Maximum", max(list1))
print ("Minimum", min(list1))
```

This should help!
This creates a list and adds only integers to the list and in the end prints the max and min values